# I need Help on fixing SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to run this SQL query in Exact Target but it's throwing an error. And I do not have visibility to error number.

Can anyone help fixing the query;

```
SELECT 
    B.SubscriberKey, B.EventDate, B.BounceCategory, C.Email, C.PolicyNumber, C.RecordType, E.SOURCE
        FROM [Bounce] B
            INNER JOIN [CONTACTS] C WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON C.UniqueContactKey = B.SubscriberKey
                INNER JOIN [EMAIL] E WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON E.PolicyNumber = C.PolicyNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I fixed it ... It was an issue with Data type in Destination Data Extension.